# Ignore document style rules in one element

Tags: css, greasemonkey

I write a greasemonkey script that adds [sticky notes](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/48919) to websites. Because there sometimes are pretty strange style rules used in some websites the sticky notes sometimes turn up messed up (or at least not looking like I want them to look).

Is there a way to say "under this element do not apply any generic stylerules"? So that rules associated with tag names are not applied, but rules associated with certain classes and ids still are. Or does anyone have a better idea on how to ensure that only my styles are applied to the sticky notes?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, that's not really possible.

In stead, you have to make sure you define every style you want manually. Don't rely on defaults. If you select your elements by I'd, they get high priority.

Comment: Well, that way I'd need to reimplement all HTML elements from scratch, because some pages redefine the basic style even for elements like list items.

Comment: Yes indeed, you will have too. That's the only way you ate sure elements are styled as they should. Iirc, components like lightbox use that same strategy too.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the "!important" keyword?

It overrides the CSS inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: That can only be applied to styles I explicitly use. I want the defaults to be reset so I don't have to redefine them manually. E.g. on google.com even list items are styled (no bullets, no indentation). And on stackoverflow list items seem to be centered. Basically I'd need to recreate all HTML elements from scratch.

Comment: @Michele Hello. How can I make !important inside styled element? Is this possible or only in external CSS rules?

Comment: Hey Boris, i dont think thats possible, infact !important overrides inline style rules.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like simply a css specificity issue to me, is it not? It seems like you should just make your css rules more specific, and resilient (don't relay on existing rules, expect defaults to be changed and write the rules that you need).

Here are some links to read up on css specificity:

- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/specificity
- http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a specificity issue. I imagine that you have your sticky notes in a single `div#stickyContainer` element, in which case you should apply overriding CSS properties to elements by the fact they belong within that element, and ensure that you reset *everything*.

That is to say, within `div#stickContainer div.sticky { ... }` make sure that you set *every* CSS property to what you would like it to be, even if you're just setting them to a typical browser default, and include the `!important` keyword following each directive.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code you want to exempt from the page's CSS rules in a separate document and use `<iframe src='[location]' />`. This is what we do for HTML examples in blog posts.

Comment: It's all JavaScript without a server component. I guess I could try to create a blank iframe and start manipulating it's contents. Or for Firefox only (which the script is anyway) I simply could encode everything in a giant `data:`-URL. (Not all browsers support giant `data:`-URLs.)